# Sort linked list using priority queue

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, priority-queue

```
public class SortList{
   class ListNode{
      ListNode next;
      int val;

    public ListNode(int val){
      this.val = val;
     }
}   
public static ListNode sortList(ListNode head) {
    if(head == null)
        return null;
    PriorityQueue<ListNode> pq = new PriorityQueue<ListNode>( (a,b) -> (a.val - b.val));
    while(head != null){
        pq.add(head);
        head = head.next;
    }
    ListNode pointer = pq.poll();
    ListNode result = pointer;
    while(pq.size() >0 ){
    System.out.println(pq.size());
        ListNode nextTemp = pq.poll();
        pointer.next = nextTemp;
        pointer = pointer.next;
    }
    return result;
}
  public static void main(String[] args){ 
  ListNode head = new ListNode(3);
  ListNode n2 = new ListNode(2);
  ListNode n3 = new ListNode(5);
  ListNode n4 = new ListNode(9);
  ListNode n5 = new ListNode(7);
  ListNode n6 = new ListNode(4);
  head.next = n2;
  n2.next = n3;
  n3.next = n4;
  n4.next = n5;
  n5.next = n6;
  n6.next = null;
  ListNode result = sortList(head);
   while(result != null){
   System.out.println(result.val);
   result = result.next;
    }
  }
 }
```

I want to sort a linked list using a priority queue, but why am I getting an infinite loop while poll() until queue is empty? The list size decreases but it increases, the priority queue never get empty.

Output:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1
1
2
3
4
6
7
9
2
3
4
6
7
9
2
3
4
6
7
9
2
3
4
6
7
9
2
3
4
6
```

......... infinite loop

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the help on how to ask a question and in particular the part about providing a [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @manchiu can you post the whole code for us ? It would be easy for me, as I don't have to write the code for ListNode and main method. Thanks

Comment: Can you also provide the error or output of your program?

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem, but you have a serious bug in your comparison. See http://blog.mischel.com/2016/11/21/subtraction-is-not-the-same-as-comparison/

Comment: Does your output of `pq.size()` show a decreasing number of items? Does it go to 0 and then stay there, or does it just give you random values? The behavior you describe does not seem possible based on the code you show. However, you do have a bug: the last node you add to the result list will point to whatever it pointed to before it went into the queue. You need to set `pointer.next = null` before returning.

Comment: You say, "the list size decreases but it increases." Which is it? Please run your program and capture the output (just a small part of it, if it becomes very long), and add it to your question.

Comment: Are you saying that the sort never completes, and the code never enters the `while` loop in `main`?

Comment: @JimMischel, the infinite loop happens in the pq.size() >0, the priority queue never gets emptied.

Comment: Please add the output from your program, showing the infinite loop.

Comment: @JimMischel added output

Comment: What would be the Space complexity of this solution? "a space complexity of O(1) means that the space required by the algorithm to process data is constant; it does not grow with the size of the data on which the algorithm is operating." So in the solution above, we are simply transforming the list to a priority queue and then building back the sorted list by plucking nodes from the priority queue. Since no new nodes are created, is the space complexity O(1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your output:

```
6
5
4
3
2
1  Up to this point, you're removing items from the priority queue
1  This is the first item in the sorted list output
2
3
4
6
7
9  End of the sorted list output
2  ?? This happens because 9 is pointing to 2 in the original list.
3
4
6
7
9
```

It's clear from your output that the code you ran is not the same as the code you posted. I know this because the output doesn't contain the value "5", and there are 7 distinct items in your output, but only 6 in your code.

Your infinite loop is not in the priority queue. You can prove this by modifying your `main()` so that it outputs a message when it starts writing the list, like this:

```
ListNode result = sortList(head);
System.out.println("Sorted list is:"); // start output
while(result != null){
    System.out.println(result.val);
    result = result.next;
}
```

The problem, as I pointed out in comments, is that the last item in the priority queue has a non-null `next` pointer. So when you remove it and add it to your result list, you end up with a loop. The result list ends up looking like this:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 6 -> 7 -> 9 ->
     ^                            \
      \                           /
       <-----<---------<--------<-
```

To fix this, modify your `sortList` method so that it sets the `next` pointer on the last item in the list to `null`:

```
while(pq.size() >0 ){
    System.out.println(pq.size());
    ListNode nextTemp = pq.poll();
    pointer.next = nextTemp;
    pointer = pointer.next;
}

pointer.next = null;  // terminate the list!!
return result;
```

This kind of error is easy to diagnose with a debugger. You could single-step the code to see *exactly* what it's doing, and you can set breakpoints so the code will stop executing at specific lines. You could have found this problem in a matter of minutes had you been using your debugger. If you don't know how to use it, learn. Now.

The other way to diagnose these problems is by placing output statements, as I showed. A simple `System.out.println("Finished the sort.");` would have told you that the sort was in fact completing, and the problem was occurring later. This is the technique we used before we had the luxury of source level debuggers, and it's still very handy today for debugging services, web pages, and other programs that aren't convenient to run in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you Jim, by adding pointer.next = null fixed the infinite loop.